# Excel takes only that no of rows which has data in c#...my code works for some excel sheet not for all

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

Excel sheets made by different different clients...that code works when i make but not when user make..is anything problem with excel sheet so , i can tell user make like that way..or i can do anything with my code.

```
private void MeterUpdateByExcelSheet(HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {
        List<string> errorMessages = new List<string>();

        int siteId = Helpers.SiteHelpers.Functions.GetSiteIdOfLoginUser().Value;

        var stream = file.InputStream;

        using (var package = new ExcelPackage(stream))
        {
            //getting number of sheets
            var sheets = package.Workbook.Worksheets;

            int totalProcessedMeters = 0;

            if (sheets.Count > 0)
            {
                var sheet = sheets.FirstOrDefault();


                //getting number of rows
                var rows = sheet.Dimension.End.Row;

                for (int row = 2; row <= rows; row++)
                {
                    //get data for a row from excel
                    var meterNo = Convert.ToString(sheet.Cells[row, 1].Value);
                    int? sanctionLoadMains = (int)Convert.ToDecimal(sheet.Cells[row, 2].Value);
                    int? sanctionLoadDG = (int)Convert.ToDecimal(sheet.Cells[row, 3].Value);
                    int? unitArea = (int)Convert.ToDecimal(sheet.Cells[row, 4].Value);
                    int? creditLimit = (int)Convert.ToDecimal(sheet.Cells[row, 5].Value);
                    int? sMSWarning = (int)Convert.ToDecimal(sheet.Cells[row, 6].Value);
                    int? sMSWarning1 = (int)Convert.ToDecimal(sheet.Cells[row, 7].Value);
                    string date = sheet.Cells[row, 8].Value.ToString();

                    DateTime billingDate;

                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(date))
                    {
                        errorMessages.Add("Date is not given for MeterNo " + meterNo + " at row " + row);
                        continue;
                    }

                    if (!DateTime.TryParseExact(date, "yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out billingDate))
                    {
                        errorMessages.Add("Date format is not correct for MeterNo. " + meterNo + " at row " + row);
                        continue;
                    }

                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(meterNo))
                    {
                        meterNo = meterNo.PadLeft(9, '0');

                        var oldMeter = _meterRepository.GetBySiteIdAndMeterNo(siteId, meterNo);

                        var newMeter = _meterRepository.GetBySiteIdAndMeterNo(siteId, meterNo);

                        int wattUnit = 1000;//loads should be multiple of 1000(watt)
                        int smsWarningUnit = 100;//sms warnings should be multiple of 100

                        if (newMeter == null)
                        {
                            errorMessages.Add("MeterNo. " + meterNo + " does not exist.");
                            continue;
                        }

                        if (sanctionLoadMains.HasValue && sanctionLoadMains >= 500)
                        {
                            newMeter.LoadSenctionMain = sanctionLoadMains.Value;
                        }

                        if (sanctionLoadDG.HasValue && sanctionLoadDG >= 500)
                        {
                            newMeter.LoadSenctionDG = sanctionLoadDG.Value;
                        }

                        if (unitArea.HasValue)
                        {
                            newMeter.UnitArea = unitArea.Value;
                        }

                        if (creditLimit.HasValue)
                        {
                            newMeter.CreditLimit = creditLimit.Value;
                        }

                        if (sMSWarning.HasValue && sMSWarning >= 100)
                        {
                            newMeter.SMSWarningAmount = sMSWarning.Value;
                        }

                        if (sMSWarning1.HasValue && sMSWarning1 >= 100)
                        {
                            newMeter.SMSWarning1Amount = sMSWarning1.Value;
                        }

                        if (billingDate != null)
                        {
                            newMeter.BillingDate = billingDate.ToIndiaDateTime();
                        }

                        _meterRepository.AddOrUpdate(newMeter);

                        var meterNotes = Helpers.MeterHelpers.Functions.GetMeterNote(oldMeter, newMeter);
                        Helpers.MeterHelpers.Functions.AddMeterNotes(meterNo, meterNotes);

                        totalProcessedMeters++;
                    }
                }

                TempData["SuccessMessage"] = totalProcessedMeters + " Meter(s) have been updated successfully";
            }
```

Comment: `it does not work` What does it mean? Are you getting any error?

Comment: @ Chetan Ranpariya , yes.. it give me exception

Comment: My telepathy is not working now a days... can you share what exception you are getting and which line of code gives you the exception?

Comment: @ Chetan Ranpariya , when i made the excel sheet same values as client made...then my code works perfectly..it get 10 rows..but when i try to upload clients excel file..then it takes 240 rows..and goes in exception..like it takes null values..

Comment: @ Chetan Ranpariya ,ex = {"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."}

Comment: @ Chetan Ranpariya, is there any way to do?

Comment: Which line of code gives you the error? There can be multiple factors here. the version of MS Office used by you and your client. The extension of the file created by you and client. Debugging only can help you.

Comment: i checked all , extensions are same..//getting number of rows
                    (var rows = sheet.Dimension.End.Row);..here the problem occur..in clients excel sheet i give all 240 rows..but on mine it give 10 rows.